# How to get attribute value using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

---

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    emplyeeDetails = XDocument.Load(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\LinqToXml\\Xmls\\" + "Employees.xml");
    var emplyees = from emp in emplyeeDetails.Descendants("Employee").Take(10)
                   orderby emp.Element("EmpId").Value ascending
                   select new
                   {
                       Id = emp.Element("EmpId").Value,
                       Name = emp.Element("Name").Value,
                       Sex = emp.Element("Sex").Value,
                       WorkPhone=emp.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type").Value,
                       HomePhone = emp.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type").Value,                               
                   };
    DgrdEmployeeDetails.ItemsSource = emplyees.ToList();
}
```

Using the code above, I can get the result below:
[image]

But I need the column `WorkPhone`'s value `424-555-0545` instead of `Home` and the column `HomePhone`'s value `423-555-0124` instead of `Home`.

What should I do for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `Where` method:

For the *Home* phone number:

```
emp.Elements("Phone").Single(phoneElement => phoneElement.Attribute("Type").Value == "Home").Value
```

For the *Work* phone number:

```
emp.Elements("Phone").Single(phoneElement => phoneElement.Attribute("Type").Value == "Work").Value
```

- `emp.Elements("Phone")` is a enumerable on all "Phone" elements of `emp`.
- `Single` will get the element that satisfy the specified property (if there are 0 or more than 1 element that satisfy the property, an error is raised).
- `phoneElement.Attribute("Type").Value` is the value of the attribute "Type" (ie "Home" or "Work")

Then, your code should be:

```
var emplyees = from emp in emplyeeDetails.Descendants("Employee").Take(10)
                orderby emp.Element("EmpId").Value ascending
                select new
                {
                    Id = emp.Element("EmpId").Value,
                    Name = emp.Element("Name").Value,
                    Sex = emp.Element("Sex").Value,
                    WorkPhone = emp.Elements("Phone").Single(phoneElement => phoneElement.Attribute("Type").Value == "Home").Value,
                    HomePhone = emp.Elements("Phone").Single(phoneElement => phoneElement.Attribute("Type").Value == "Work").Value,
                };
```

If the element `emp` may have no *Work* phone or *Home* phone number, the above code will raise an exception in the `Single`. To deal with this case you have to change your code to:

```
(string)emp.Elements("Phone").SingleOrDefault(phoneElement => phoneElement.Attribute("Type").Value == "Home")
```

`SingleOrDefault` will equal `null` if no "Phone" element satisfy the condition and the `string` cast on a `XElement` is equivalent to `XElement.Value`.

Comment: Alternatively in C# 6+, instead of casting to avoid a `NullReferenceException`, you can use the [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). So it would look like: `Name = emp.Element("Name")?.Value;`

Answer (score 3):

This code will work even if there is any `Phone` elements exist for employee:

```
var emplyees = 
    from emp in emplyeeDetails.Descendants("Employee").Take(10)
    let phones = emp.Descendants("Phone")
    orderby (int)emp.Element("EmpId")
    select new
    {
        Id = (int)emp.Element("EmpId"),
        Name = (string)emp.Element("Name"),
        Sex = (string)emp.Element("Sex"),
        WorkPhone = (string)phones.FirstOrDefault(p => (string)p.Attribute("Type") == "Work"),
        HomePhone = (string)phones.FirstOrDefault(p => (string)p.Attribute("Type") == "Home")                               
    };
```

Use casting elements to `string`, `int`, etc instead of accessing `Value` property. Why? Because if there is some missing element or attribute in your xml, then you will get a `NullReferenceException`. But casting will return default value instead. So, code above will parse even xml like this:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone>524-777-1234</Phone>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```